# Camel - XML body sometimes does not get transfered completely using https4 component

Tags: xml, rest, apache-camel, http-post

We are transfering XML data via Apache Camel using the HTTPS4 component. Sometimes it happens that one file is not transfered completely and can not be processed by the receiving system. If it is discovered I can send the same file via the same way and it's working as expected. Last night it happened with one of 105 files. 
The size of the files is between 5 and 10 mb. 
The file is received like

```
<tag>bla
 <anothertag>blabla</anothertag>
<ta
```

The uri in camel is configured like

```
<to uri="https4://someserver.com:12345/some/thing/create?authMethod=Basic&amp;authUsername=user&amp;authPassword=pwd&amp;authenticationPreemptive=true" />
```

Any ideas if there is proactive way of solving that issue?
I am thinking of just reducing the size but we have another interface with XMLs with about the same size and there we are not experiencing any issues.

This is how the route is configured:

```
<route id="postSomething">
    <from uri="file:/opt/camel/interfaceId?move=.done />
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
        <constant>POST</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="https4://someserver.com:12345/some/thing/create?authMethod=Basic&amp;authUsername=user&amp;authPassword=pwd&amp;authenticationPreemptive=true" /> 
</route>
```

Comment: What does the logs say? Have you tried the same files to a local server? Check for network error?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: everything I can see in our logs is that the file was transfered successfully and receiving side does not see any error, as well. The error happens when they are trying to validate the xml.
Our assumption so far is that the connection is maybe closed before the file is transfered completely. We are already getting a response with a HTTP Code 202 but the transfer wasn't completed. 
I guess I have to wait for our admin until we can check for network errors.

Comment: It could be that the response is sent before the whole file is written on the client. Are you sending the file as chunked (streaming) or with content-length (i.e. reading the whole and then sending it)? For large files I would go with chunked and you may  need to configure Camel to use chunked in the http settings.

Comment: Why does validation fail? Sounds like an invalid file.

Comment: @Namphibian yes, the file is invalid because it is not transfered completely as I stated in my question. Half of the information is missing as well as the tags closing the xml file. But it only occured with one out of 105 files we transfered.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I will look into the settings for the HTTPS4 component, maybe I'll something. I also added the configuration of the route to my original question.

Comment: @Alex so you can confirm that file was valid before transfer.

Comment: @Namphibian yes, it definitely was valid before transfer. We are storing the files in our filesystem in a place where camel has access. I could even send the exact same file when our customer told us that the file was broken and then the transfer was succesful.